# How does 'git status' cache the workdir information and how is it used the next time?

Tags: git

I have a project of 200.000 files and I noticed that `git status` takes around 2.0 seconds to execute the very first time. However, on the second run it takes around 0.03s. How does Git speed up the second run?

If we only take `file size` and `mtime` into consideration, what shortcut is used on the second run? From my understanding Git needs to still evaluate the file size and mtime to understand which files got modified, no?

Comment: Git is open source. If you really care about this, read the code and see what Git does.

Answer (score 2):

My guess the difference is because of operating system cache, not Git cache. First time you run `git status` every directory must be read from disk which is slow even on SSD disks. But then the OS caches all directories so next time it returns data from its cache in memory which is much, much faster. After some time the cache will expire or overwritten by other OS needs (other buffers and caches) and `git status` will run slower again.

Comment: That makes sense, but I couldn't see that performance gain in my own Go app. It just walks over the directories and reads mtime and file size, always takes 2 seconds.

Comment: @HelloWorld I surely saw the effect of OS caching many times when I run the same `rsync` (incremental backups) a few times a day. First time after reboot it took more than a minute and the server spins the disk quite loud. After a few times it took about 30 seconds. Repeat a dozen of times and it took 10 seconds, no visible disk activity.